# How to clear properly in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, garbage-collection

How do I clear properly in Java when I have further referenced objects in another object. Let's say I have the following example:

Continent
|________Country
         |______City

Therefore a Continent can have several countries, which in turn may multiple cities.

```
 public class City {
      public String name;

      public City(String name) {
          this.name = name;
      }
 }

 public class Country {
      public String name;
      public ArrayList<City> cities = new ArrayList<City>();

      public Country(String name) {
          this.name = name;
      }
 }

 public class Continent {
     public String name;
     public ArrayList<Country> countries = new ArrayList<Country>();

     public Country(String name) {
         this.name = name;
     }
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
     City city1 = new City("Berlin");
     City city2 = new City("Paris");
     City city3 = new City("Munich");

     Country country1 = new Country("Germany");
     Country country2 = new Country("France");

     country1.cities.add(city1);
     country1.cities.add(city3);

     country2.cities.add(city2);

     Continent continent1 = new Continent("Europe");
     continent1.countries.add(country1);
     continent1.countries.add(country2);
 }
```

As you can see I have a Continent object which has multiple countries in the ArrayList which can have again multiple Cities each. Now my question is:

As far as I know, the Garbage Collector doesn't touch referenced objects, so that I have to make sure to delete all the references. So, when I'm correct, then

```
continent1.countries.clear();
```

is not sufficient. In this case, is it sufficient if I clear the ArrayList "countries" in the object continent and all the ArrayLists "cities" in each object Country? Or do I miss something or perhaps am I completely wrong?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'as far as I know, the garbage collector doesn't touch referenced objects'?

Comment: First of all when you do `continent1.countries.clear()`, there is no guarantee that garbage collector will run immediately. And when it will run it will automatically mark the unreferenced objects and then sweep them. You don't have to worry about that.

Comment: Does it also work, even when the object in the ArrayList countries still have the references to the City objects? Because they are still reachable.

Comment: Objects that are reachable are not garbage collected. This is rather basic.

Comment: To summarize: just clearing the "top" object e.g. continent is not sufficient. So i have to clear the arraylist in continent, and within all the arraylists in the "low level" objects e.g. countries. Correct?

Do i have also to set the "lowest" objects, in this case the cities, to null?

Comment: You don’t have to clear anything. When the `main` method returns, the entire heap memory is given back to the operating system.

Comment: If those objects are only reachable via the top arraylist, clearing that will make them unreachable, which will allow them all to be garage-collected. Again this is rather basic.

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding of how the garbage collector works is flawed.

Most algorithms (there are many different ones) start by creating a root set of referencable objects.  That is those on the stack, in registers, etc.  Each object in the root set is marked as live and then references to other objects are recursively traced (and marked).  This ensures that all referencable objects (no matter how deep) are identified.  This is referred to as a precise collector.

The collector is then able to reclaim the space used by objects that are no longer required (i.e. are not marked as live).  How that happens depends on whether the objects are in the young or old generation and what algorithm is being used (CMS, parallel, G1, etc).

In your case, you are maintaining separate references to all the objects so even if continent1 ceased to be referenced the Country and City objects would not be collected.  If the only references to the Country and City objects were via the Continent object then they could be collected when continent1 was collected.

The key point here is that you, the developer, do not need to have any responsibility for telling the JVM and GC when objects are no longer required.  It all happens automatically.